# Gunicorn Two-way SSL Error "SSL_ERROR_UNKNOWN_CA_ALERT"

Tags: python, ssl, gunicorn

I am running a Python3 app via [Gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/index.html) with two-way SSL configured. This requires a local cert/key to verify the app as well as a ca_certs file to verify the client. Gunicorn relies on the standard `ssl` module in Python, particularly the `wrap_socket` method.

The service starts and responds to curl requests fine when I use self-signed certificates for both server and client authentication. However when I use certificates signed by another CA, I get an error `SSL_ERROR_UNKNOWN_CA_ALERT`.

**A working setup, with self-signed certs:**

```
# Server cert
openssl req \
       -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key \
       -x509 -days 365 -out domain.crt

# Client (CA) cert    
openssl req \
       -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout twoway.key \
       -x509 -days 365 -out twoway.crt
```

With Gunicorn configured as follows:

```
keyfile = domain.key
certfile = domain.crt
cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ca_certs=twoway.crt
```

And curling as follows:

```
curl -vk --key twoway.key --cert twoway.crt https://my.service
```

Produces a successful response:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=AU; ST=Some-State; O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
*  start date: Dec  7 18:35:54 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  7 18:35:54 2019 GMT
*  issuer: C=AU; ST=Some-State; O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET /manage/info HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2018 18:26:19 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 73
```

**A failing setup, with a different series of certs:**

With Gunicorn configured as follows:

```
keyfile = my_service_key.key
certfile = my_service_cert.crt
cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ca_certs = my_trusted_clients.crt
```

And curling as follows:

```
curl -vk --key my_trusted_key.key --cert my_trusted_clients.crt https://my.service
```

Produces an error:

```
About to connect() to localhost port 5000 (#0)
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql/etc/pki/nssdb
warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
skipping SSL peer certificate verification
NSS: client certificate from file
    subject: CN=mycn,OU=abc,O=def,...
NSS error -12195
Closing connection #0
SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

Any thoughts on whether I am configuring this the wrong way? And why self-signed certs are working but other certs are not?

Note this config worked previously when using [Stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html#SERVICE-LEVEL-OPTIONS), where I set the `verify` level to 4 ("Ignore the chain and only verify the peer certificate."). If there is something similar in Python I believe that would get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is be possible as of Gunicorn 19.9.

As well as having the complete certificate chain on the server, in order to validate the client/peer certificate, I believe you will need to be able to [configure the `SSLContext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#verifying-certificates), and especially be able to set [`ssl.CERT_REQUIRED`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.CERT_REQUIRED) when in server-mode.

Gunicorn 19.9 (and master at the time of writing) does not currently use the `SSLContext`-based wrapper on the connection, so this is not possible, see https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1140 .